# Error on sign in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign in in firebase using email and password but I'm not able to make it work. I'm getting this error:
The email address is badly formatted.

Has anyone else come across with this error?

Email: foofoo@gmail.com
Pwd: fofo1234

I'm using this code to sign in

```
private void signIn(final String email, final String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("foofoo@gmail.com", "fofo1234").addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some logs from when this fails?  Also you are calling signInWithEmailAndPassword which only works for existing accounts, have you signed **up** with these credentials?